# Add war to spring boot embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7, openkm

I have a spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE application that uses embedded tomcat webserver and uses [OpenKM](https://www.openkm.com/) via it's SDK.

Now, I have some integration tests that use `restassured` lib to make REST calls and verify response structure. My idea is to integrate `OpenKM.war` into this wmbedded tomcat and be able to run this tests without need to have openkm application running on some different server.

this is how I make embedded tomcat to read and deploy openkm.war:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }

            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                new File(tomcat.getServer().getCatalinaBase(), "webapp").mkdirs();
                try {
                    tomcat.addWebapp("/okm", new ClassPathResource("webapp/openkm.war").getFile().toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add okm", ex);
                }
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

deploy takes way to longer than on the standalone tomcat webserver that is shipped with openkm, but it deploys.

However deployment process fails with:

```
IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:/tmp/tomcat.2352216859213135410.8080/openkm.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tomcat.2352216859213135410.8080/openkm.xml (No such file or directory)
```

I have this file (plus server.xml, context.xml) alongside openkm.war file, but it seems like embedded tomcat doesn't know about it.

All these files are located in `src/main/resources/webapp`.

So, I would like to know what configuration piece am I missing or whether there is whole other better to achieve what I want?

Comment: I have been faced with tmp dir issue before, can you try manually creating `tmp` dir and running your server?

Comment: that directory exists. problem is that file is really not there so I think tomcat doesn't know about it and how to treat it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like;

```
StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/okm", new ClassPathResource("webapp/openkm.war").getFile().toString());
WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "{target mount path}",
        new File("src/main/resources/webapp").getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
ctx.setResources(resources);
```

So that you can have your `src/main/resources/webapp/` folder mounted on `{target mount path}` in tomcat deployment. Though I am unsure on this path? Can you try with `"/"`, and maybe `"/WEB-INF/"` ? I have no way to test in my local currently but I hope this will help somehow.

You can mount individual files with `FileResourceSet` as well, if you need different files in different folders in tomcat.